# Finding Distinct Values across 2 tables is not working

Tags: sql, sql-server, join, distinct, dbeaver

I have 2 tables (I've only shown select fields):

**Table A:**

```
    <LOCATION CODE>
    ACT   
    NSWNS    
    OSUSA
    Parra
    Parra
    Parra
    ACT
    ACT
```

**Table B (A lookup table):**

```
<CODE>    <DESCRIPTION>
ACT        Australian Capital Territory
NSWNS      New South Whales - North South
OSUSA      Overseas - USA
Parra      Parramatta
```

"Description" is of type 'text'.
"Code" is of type 'varchar'.
"location" is a type of t_code_key.

I'm trying to perform join on both of these table so that I receive a unique list of 'Code' items from Table A long with their full description name from Table B.

I want to get something like this:

```
<CODE>   <DESCRIPTION>
ACT      Australian Capital Territory
Parra    Parramatta
NSW      New South Whales
```

I've tried the following two queries I wrote but I'm not getting any luck just errors:

```
select mp.location, ct.description
from 
    (select DISTINCT CAST(description AS VARCHAR(MAX)) AS ct FROM code_table)
    full outer JOIN
    (select DISTINCT location from mailout_profile) as mp 
        on ct.code = mp.location;

select mp.location, ct.description
from 
    (select DISTINCT convert(VARCHAR(MAX), description) AS ct FROM code_table)
    full outer JOIN
    (select DISTINCT location from mailout_profile) as mp 
        on ct.code = mp.location;
```

**The errors I'm getting are:**

```
SQL Error [156] [S0001]: Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'full'.
  Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'full'.
  Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'full'.
```

Would appreciate help thanks!! :)

Comment: Syntax of FULL OUTER JOIN must be like this: SELECT column_name(s)
FROM table1
FULL OUTER JOIN table2
ON table1.column_name = table2.column_name
WHERE condition;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try this:

```
WITH r1 (loc) AS
    (SELECT DISTINCT LOCATION FROM [mailout_profile])
SELECT Code, Description FROM r1
FULL OUTER JOIN [code_table] ct ON r1.loc =  ct.Code
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks this did the trick however I received a lot of duplicate records. I fixed that problem by adding a WHERE clause with a couple of other conditions. Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

You can use the below query to get the desired result -

**Sample Data**

```
Declare @TableA table
(LocationCode varchar(20))

Insert into @TableA
values

    ('ACT'   ),
    ('NSWNS' ),   
    ('OSUSA'    ),
    ('Parra'    ),
    ('Parra'    ),
    ('Parra'    ),
    ('ACT'  ),
    ('ACT'  )


Declare @TableB table
(Code varchar(20), Description varchar(100))

Insert into @TableB
values
('ACT'    ,  'Australian Capital Territory'   ),
('NSWNS'  ,  'New South Whales - North South' ),
('OSUSA'  ,  'Overseas - USA'                 ),
('Parra'  ,  'Parramatta'                     )
```

**Query**

```
select DISTINCT LocationCode, [Description] 
From @TableA a inner join @TableB b on a.LocationCode = b.Code
```

Comment: Thanks, did you just create 2 temporary tables? This => Declare @TableA table

Comment: Yes, this is temprary table variable just to demonstrate, you can replace table variables name with your actual table names.

Comment: Thank you Mukesh. The actual tables actually have a million records each so I can't manually insert records into a temporary table myself but I learned something here. :) I upvoted your answer.

Comment: There is no need to use the temprary table variable, this is just as an example - use your table directly like this - select DISTINCT LocationCode, [Description] 
From ActualTableName1 a inner join ActualTableName2 b on a.LocationCode = b.Code